# Google AdWords API List of Product Listing Ads

Tags: api, google-ads-api

So here is my problem: I need to get a list of all ProductAd Ids by using the AdWordsAPI. I have already tried to use the AdGroupAdService, but it gives me just one Product-Listing-Ad ID. When I am in the UI, there are about 2000 Ads, so this seems to be the wrong way.
I also thought about using the Shopping Performance Report, but I can't enable includeZeroImpressions so there are a lot of products missing in the CSV-ResultFile.

Now my question is, how i can get a list of all the Product-Listing-Ad IDs of the available Products?
EDIT:

```
// Get the AdGroupAdService.
    AdGroupAdServiceInterface adGroupAdService = new AdWordsServices().get(session, AdGroupAdServiceInterface.class);

    int offset = 0;
    boolean morePages = true;

    // Create selector.
    SelectorBuilder builder = new SelectorBuilder();
    Selector selector =
        builder
            .fields(AdGroupAdField.Id, AdGroupAdField.Status)
            .orderAscBy(AdGroupAdField.Id)
            .offset(offset)
            .limit(GoogleConstants.GOOGLE_PAGE_SIZE)
            // .equals(AdGroupAdField.AdGroupId, adGroupId.toString())
            // .in(AdGroupAdField.Status, "ENABLED", "PAUSED", "DISABLED")
            .equals("AdType", "PRODUCT_AD")
            .build();


        while (morePages) {
            // Get all ads.
            AdGroupAdPage page;
            page = adGroupAdService.get(selector);

            displayAds(page);

            offset += GoogleConstants.GOOGLE_PAGE_SIZE;
            selector = builder.increaseOffsetBy(GoogleConstants.GOOGLE_PAGE_SIZE).build();
            morePages = offset < page.getTotalNumEntries();
        }
```

I want to use this list to build an AdGroupPartitionTree with Offer-IDs as Dimension.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201601/AdGroupAdService.ProductAd

Comment: yes, I read the docs, but either I missed something or did something wrong on my code. when i try to get a list of product ads, using these fields, I only get about 20 products while there are more than 2000 on this account. So I don't know what i am doing wrong. I will post my code in the above article

Comment: Yes please, post your code

Comment: Ok, i compared some IDs and it seems to be the case, that the OfferId is equal to the Customer_Article_ID from the input-feed.
Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT instead shopping performance report. And set up true for includeZeroImpressions.

Here is doc: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/product-partition-report

Field 'Id' is your ProductAd id, you can also get OfferId this way.